# Is this an ok implementation of an UnorderedPair?

Tags: c#

I want to create pair, where `new UnorderedPair(ObjA, ObjB) == UnorderedPair(ObjB, ObjA)` returns `true`. I also want to avoid any (un)boxing.

Have I gone about this in the correct way?

```
public struct UnorderedPair<T> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<T>>
{
    public T A;
    public T B;

    public UnorderedPair(T a, T b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return A.GetHashCode() ^ B.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<T> other)
    {
        return (other.A.Equals(A) && other.B.Equals(B)) ||
               (other.A.Equals(B) && other.B.Equals(A));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals((UnorderedPair<T>)obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UnorderedPair<T> a, UnorderedPair<T> b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UnorderedPair<T> a, UnorderedPair<T> b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing: I would make the `struct` [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751911/why-are-c-sharp-structs-immutable/3753640#3753640) since mutable `struct`s [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) [really](https://web.archive.org/web/20220718052609/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/) [bad](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability) [unintended](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab026c2a-21cd-4c30-b7b1-88b07493172d/immutable-structs?forum=csharplanguage) [effects](https://web.archive.org/web/20200129202000/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/blomqvist/archive/2009/06/15/struct-vs-class-and-immutability.aspx). Otherwise, this is a good, solid implementation.

```
public struct UnorderedPair<T> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<T>>
{
    private readonly T a;

    private readonly T b;

    public UnorderedPair(T a, T b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public T A
    {
        get
        {
            return this.a;
        }
    }

    public T B
    {
        get
        {
            return this.b;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.a.GetHashCode() ^ this.b.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<T> other)
    {
        return (other.A.Equals(this.a) && other.B.Equals(this.b)) ||
               (other.A.Equals(this.b) && other.B.Equals(this.a));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals((UnorderedPair<T>)obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UnorderedPair<T> a, UnorderedPair<T> b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UnorderedPair<T> a, UnorderedPair<T> b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

and because time marches on, here's a more compact and performant C# 7.2 version:

```
public readonly struct UnorderedPair<T> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<T>>
{
    public UnorderedPair(in T a, in T b) => (this.A, this.B) = (a, b);

    public T A { get; }

    public T B { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => this.A.GetHashCode() ^ this.B.GetHashCode();

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<T> other) => (other.A.Equals(this.A) && other.B.Equals(this.B))
        || (other.A.Equals(this.B) && other.B.Equals(this.A));

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => this.Equals((UnorderedPair<T>)obj);

    public static bool operator ==(in UnorderedPair<T> a, in UnorderedPair<T> b) => a.Equals(b);

    public static bool operator !=(in UnorderedPair<T> a, in UnorderedPair<T> b) => !(a == b);
}
```

Comment: Just a question.  Is there any reason you would use a readonly private variable a and b over just having a private set accessor on the public A and B objects?

Comment: `readonly` does not allow any other methods or properties to modify those variables. a `private set` accessor would allow other methods/properties in the class to modify them. I prefer `readonly` to signify intent - once they're set in the constructor, they're off-limits to anything else.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  Guess I hadn't thought it all the way through.